# TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting in python connecting with postgresql

Tags: python-3.x, database, string-formatting, postgresql-9.5

It seems like all no error in the code but no idea why I'm getting this. 
I was creating a simple GUI app which store user details to a database(postgresql) and also they will be able to search for entries in database. This particular error ocures in this search() function so I haven't added the rest of the code. If necessary I can add them. 
Hope I will get some solutions from this community.

```
def search(id):
    conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname="postgres",user="postgres",password="1018",host="localhost",port="5432")
    mycursor = conn.cursor()
    query = '''select * from demotab where id=%s '''
    mycursor.execute(query, (id))
    row = mycursor.fetchone()
    print(row)
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Getting this error below

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "appwithDB.py", line 51, in <lambda>
    search_button = Button(newframe, text="Search", command=lambda : search(entry_search.get()))
  File "appwithDB.py", line 71, in search
    mycursor.execute(query, (id))
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to `mycursor.execute` must be an iterable containing the values to insert in the query

You can use a list: `mycursor.execute(query, [id])`
or a one-element tuple: `mycursor.execute(query, (id,))`

Notice the comma. `(id)` is the same than `id`. In python, the comma is making the tuple, not the parenthesis.

Comment: Great thanks it worked I didn't expect this quick response. But I would like to have more information about the usage of iterable there. Why it is necessary to use iterable there and why not just a variable?

Comment: Your query may contain several variables, so you must use an iterable, that contains as many elements as the number of "%" in your query string.


This is the choice that was made by the writers of the library.


If my answer helped you, please mark it as "accepted"